# Use Entity Data Model in two projects with synchronized data between both of them

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, ado.net

I've a solution containing 3 projects.

1. EDM framework connect to a SQL database
2. Desktop Application 1
3. Desktop Application 2

I'm using the EDM project in both desktop applications, without a problem, but any database change made by one of them is not seen by the other. I.e.: if any change is made by application A to database, application B has to be restarted to be able to see those changes.

How can I synchronize those changes between projects? Any way to "say" to Entities to use the most updated data? Ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever your Entity Container Name is you will have to use the following:

dataEntity.Refresh();

Look into it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738618.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could place all the code that changes when the database changes in a single dll, shared by both of the projects.